2 types of 2-series flyback converter

There are two types of flyback converters.
From what I understand, the flyback converter with the diode snubber on the right has the advantage of reusing the leakage inductance energy back into the power supply side. On the other hand, the conventional flyback topology with two series-connected MOSFETs, as shown on the left, primarily has the benefit of reducing the voltage stress by half compared to a standard flyback design. Beyond this, it doesn't seem to offer any additional significant advantages.
If there are other advantages or disadvantages that I haven't considered, please describe them.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

sp kang - Hi, Where did the schematics come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help])

The one on the left doesn't even work, because it doesn't have a switch. There are also definitely other types of flyback converter than those shown here; both of these are unusual types.

I wouldn't consider the diodes "snubbers".  They are additional switches.  I would (very slightly) disagree with @Hearth that the two-transistor flyback is unusual, it's been around for years, but maybe unusual in the sense that the vast majority of flybacks are built to be inexpensive and use a single transistor and snubber or active clamp.  Driving the high-side FET makes the 2-T flyback more complicated and limits the choice of controllers.

The Left diagram wastes more power due to the Snubber resistors .So overall the right diagram is best for efficiency .There is little cost difference so the right is correct .The left will perform over a greater range ,it will do very low input volts .You will see RCD snubbers on cheap low power mains in stuff that does 90 to 270 VAC .
